# Difficult problem with multi index in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1", "1", "1", "2", "3"], "value" : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]})
df.set_index(["ID", "value"], inplace=True)
```

By doing so I have multiindex "ID" and "value" like below:

[image]

What can I do so as to have this multiindex like on the result like below:

[image]

I tried also other way on the data frame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1", "1", "1", "2", "3"], "value" : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], "a} : [1,2,3,4,5)
df.set_index(["ID", "value"], inplace=True)
```

And code:

```
#temporaly display all levels of MultiIndex
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse',False):
    print (df)
```

But result is not a "elegant" DataFrame

[image]

Comment: Please choose a more specific question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about diplaying, by default are hidden repeated values, [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options) :

> display.multi_sparse, True,
> “Sparsify” MultiIndex display (don’t display repeated elements in outer levels within groups)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1", "1", "1", "2", "3"], "value" : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]})
df.set_index(["ID", "value"], inplace=True)
df['tmp'] = 1

#temporaly display all levels of MultiIndex
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse',False):
    print (df)
          tmp
ID value     
1  10       1
1  11       1
1  12       1
2  13       1
3  14       1
```

For set always display all levels (not default option):

```
pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)
print (df)
```

Comment: DO you know other way ? id does not work for me :/

Comment: @bruno845 - Can you explian more not working?

Comment: @bruno845 - Is possible see your not working code?

Comment: because you add another column, I do not want to add another column

Comment: you add note "temporarly" but i nedd to have multiindex constantly

Comment: @bruno845 - hmmm, so you have only 2 column in input real data? If yes, I cannot diplay it like in question. If multiple columns, just remove `df['tmp'] = 1`

Comment: Hmm maybe your answer will be ok if I add another daya I will check, nevertheless I give you best answer

Comment: jezrael nevertheless I do not have result as DataFrame using your code

Comment: @bruno845 - I am a bit confused, what is elegant output?

Comment: @bruno845 - If ned set permanetly wh ynot use `pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)` ?