# reorder data in pandas pivot_table function

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I've a sample dataframe

```
region   headquarter      sales    base    %growth    month_year
   X      Los Angeles     1000     2000      30        202101
   X      Florida City    2000     2000      20        202101
   X      Los Angeles     5000     6000      70        202001
   X      Florida City    4000     4500      45        202001
```

I'm trying to pivot the data using

```
data = data.pivot_table(columns=['month_year'], values=['sales', 'base', '%growth'], index=['region', 'headquarter'])

print(data)

>                              %growth          base           sales
         |               |   202001  202101  202001 202101   202001 202101
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  region |  headquarter  |
     x   |  Los Angeles  |    70    30     6000   2000       5000    1000
         |  Florida City |    45    20     4000   2000       4500    2000
```

The values are not in order which I've mentioned in the above snippet.

How can I re-structure my data to (by also repeating the row labels)

```
>                            202001                 202101
                         Sales  base  %growth    Sales  base  %growth     
   region   headquarter
     X      Los Angeles   5000   6000    70       1000   2000     30
     X      Florida City  4500   4000    45       2000   2000     20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([data['month_year'].unique(), ['Sales','base','%growth']])
data = data.pivot_table(columns=['month_year'], 
                        values=['Sales', 'base', '%growth'], 
                        index=['headquarter']).swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1).reindex(mux, axis=1)

print(data)
             202101               202001              
              Sales  base %growth  Sales  base %growth
headquarter                                           
Florida City   2000  2000      20   4000  4500      45
Los Angeles    1000  2000      30   5000  6000      70
```

EDIT:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([data['month_year'].unique(), ['sales','base','%growth']])


data = data.pivot_table(columns=['month_year'], 
                        values=['sales', 'base', '%growth'], 
                        index=['region', 'headquarter']).swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1).reindex(mux, axis=1)


print (data)
                    202101               202001              
                     sales  base %growth  sales  base %growth
region headquarter                                           
X      Florida City   2000  2000      20   4000  4500      45
       Los Angeles    1000  2000      30   5000  6000      70
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. How do I rectify the values order in the pivot. I'm trying to get `sales base %growth`, but the pivot keeps giving me `%growth  base  sales`?

Comment: @astroboy1 - yop, please use last version of answer.

Comment: I've tried this, but when I add multiple column to index (as in the edited question) in pivot, your method isn't working.

Comment: @astroboy1 - How was edded multiple columns to Index?

Comment: `data = data.pivot_table(columns=['month_year'], values=['sales', 'base', '%growth'], index=['region', 'headquarter']` I've also mentioned new column region in index here.

Comment: @astroboy1 - Added to answer solution above and for me working perfectly.

Comment: Is the data in the region column getting repeated in the end result data? Its not working for me. idk why.

Comment: @astroboy1 - Sure, only not diplayed. Wrong copied data, so edited answer again. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732745/difficult-problem-with-multi-index-in-dataframe-in-python-pandas/65732783#65732783) for explained more.

Comment: I've also tried with the display cotent option, didn't work for me. So I have raised a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66972016/how-to-repeat-row-labels-in-pandas-pivot-table-function-and-export-it-as-excel?noredirect=1#comment118443056_66972016) again.

Comment: @astroboy1 - So problem is write MultiIndex to excel? It is really not easy like pointed anky.

Comment: Yes getting the data in excel is the big deal here. I'm looking for other ways to do that. But couldn't able to.

Comment: @astroboy1 - unfortuantely only default way exist or some kind of hack solutions, Try looking for write multiindex to excel